# bcdedit command failing with parameter is incorrect

Tags: windows-10, vmware

I'm trying to get VMware workstation to work on a win10 enterprise system after turning off device/Credential guard.  Following the instructions here https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146361  I'm stuck on the following command.
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} path "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi"

I have tried numberous various path parameters but it keeps saying that its incorrect.  Any asistance would be greatly appreciated.